# How to kill a process based on the partial content of its window title?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I start a command window with a similar command:

```
start "DUMMYCOMMANDWINDOW"
```

I can then close the window using this command:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ DUMMY*" /f /t
```

What I'd like to do, however, is to close the window based on its partial title. Something like this:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ *COMMANDWINDOW" /f /t
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It's not really documented, but you can use the `*` wildcard character only at the very *end* of the string.

Answer (score 7):

Using PowerShell, you can do the following:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like '*commandwindow' } | Stop-Process
```

`Get-Process` returns a list of all processes, the `Where-Object` clause filters it based on the window title, and `Stop-Process` is similar to taskkill.

Comment: Avoid trying this with `-EQ` operator! That doesn't work.. Wasted a few hours on the ideocyncracies of Powershell with that! Had to do <title>* syntax with `-like`. In my case all I wanted was the pId. so wrapped in brackets and used `.Id`

Answer (score 1):

An * cannot be at the start. Taskkill does not support it. But "COMMANDWINDOW*" should work regardless.